# Почему InnoDB медленне MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

Один и тот же запрос в таблицу с 3млн строк

```
SELECT order_id, x as x1,y as y1, MAX(x) as x2, MAX(y) as y2  FROM `items` where order_id>0 group by order_id LIMIT 5000
```

выдает время выполнения:

для MyISAM (только первичный индекс) 0.11 сек
для InnoDB (только первичный индекс) 0.29 сек
для InnoDB (индексы по всем полям) 1.17 сек

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**
для MyISAM при добавлении индекса по order_id запрос уменьшился с 0.11 сек до 0.0026 сек!!! полный провал InnoDB...

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT-то приложите

Comment: приложил картинку. оно?

Comment: Да, InnoDB медленнее MyISAM. У него несколько другие преимущества, транзакционность например.

Comment: Я очень советую почитать эти вопрос и ответ: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75091/why-are-simple-selects-on-innodb-100x-slower-than-on-myisam

Comment: кратко и емко!!)) так что EXPLAIN показал? вообще присматривался к Inno - нужны частые select и update, insert вообще не будет

Comment: ага, оно самое.

Comment: и почему-то в InnoDB в EXPLINE кол-во строк меньше 1млн?

Comment: @ Pavel Gurkov - still far too slow for any real world usage. Вот что я оттуда почерпнул касаемо InnoDB

Comment: Вы перед тем, как писать "полный провал" посмотрите-то, что у вас в InnoDB используемых индексов нет.

Comment: на картинке 3 запрос сверху - есть же индекс по order_id! ПРОВАЛ InnoDB состоялся в рамках текущего поста и в рамках моей задачи, зачем обобщать?)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 и 2 запросы не используют индексы. Key = null
Вы строите рабочие , но **некорректные** запросы с точки зрения SQL (работает в вашем случае потому что это MySQL , видимо запущенный по умолчанию в нестрогом режиме).
Если вы хотите сравнить производительность, то уберите GROUP BY для начала и в Where используйте только колонку с первичным индексом. По факту ваш текущий тест не показывает ровным счетом ничего.
GROUP BY сверх того еще использует дополнительные индексы оптимизации, о которых можно почитать в литературе (loose index scan)

Учите теорию!

Comment: Group By - это основа моего запроса как бы. В таблице хранится по несколько строк на один номер заказа order_id, в каждой из них хранятся параметры заказа, но в каждой из них order_id одинаков. Мне нужно получать ДВЕ строки - в одной минимальное значение X и Y (это однозначно первая строка из вышеуказанных), во второй максимально значение X и Y (это однозначно последняя строка из вышеуказанных). Возможно, запрос неверен и можно построить иначе?

Comment: убедитесь, что индекс (INDEX) установлен на order_id. Ключевое правило при работе с GROUP BY - вы должны выбирать только те колонки, которые используются в GROUP BY или применять к ним агрегирующую функцию(min, max, avg etc). SELECT order_id, MAX(x) as x2, MAX(y) as y2  FROM `items` where order_id>0 group by order_id LIMIT 5000
Если нужно , чтобы минимумы были во 2й строке обязательно, добавьте аналогичный запрос, только используя MIN, через UNION ALL

Comment: INDEX на order_id установлен, ваш вариант запроса ситуацию абсолютно не изменил... а вообще сам запрос (мой вариант) верен? я не ожидал от GROUP BY выдачи двух строк!! вроде как он выдает ОДНУ строку всегда... а мне как раз две надо, на каждый order_id вытащить по две строки - с минималкой по X и с максималкой по X. хотя исходя из формирования таблицы эти строки можно было бы определить не как MIN MAX а сугубо по id (в таблице строго по возрастанию расположено)

Comment: обновил пост, для MyISAM при добавлении индекса по order_id запрос идет 0.0026 сек!!! полный провал InnoDB...